# How does circular import work exactly in Python

Tags: python, import, circular-dependency

I have the following code (run with CPython 3.4):

[image: How I expect import to work]

Basically the red arrows explain how I expected the import to work:
h is defined before importing from test2.
So when test2 imports test1 it's not an empty module anymore (with h)
And h is the only thing that test2 wants.

I think this contradicts with http://effbot.org/zone/import-confusion.htm

Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're missing is the fact that `from X import Y`, does not solely imports `Y`. It imports the module X *first*. It's mentioned in the page:

> **from X import a, b, c** imports the module X, and creates references in the current namespace to the given objects. Or in other words, you can now use a and b and c in your program.

So, this statement:

```
from test import h
```

Does not stop importing when it reaches the definition of `h`.

Let's change the file:

*test.py*

```
h = 3
if __name__ != '__main__': #check if it's imported
    print('I'm still called!')
...
```

When you run `test.py`, you'll get `I'm still called!` before the error.

The condition checks whether the script is imported or not. In your edited code, if you add the condition, you'll `print` it only when it acts as the main script, not the imported script.

Here is something to help:

1. test imports test2 (h is defined)
2. test2 imports test, then it meets the condition.
3. The condition is false - test is imported -, so, test2 is not going to look for `test2.j` - it doesn't exist just yet.

Hope this helps!

Comment: ok I did more test.
I changed all `from ... import ...` to import, and in test.py:
`import test2
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(test2.j)`

this will work, but without the `if` condition check it will raise AttributeError. What's the difference?

Comment: It's just like the article says.

Comment: That definitely helps! Thanks!