# Python 3 relative circular import

Tags: python-3.x, import, circular-dependency, relative-import

File module/a.py

```
from . import b
```

File module/b.py

```
from . import a
```

This results in an ImportError, telling it can not import a (or b, depending on which is imported first). However, changing one of them (respectively) to an absolute import works.

```
import module.a
```

Choosing

```
import module.a as a
```

results in a NameError, though.

Can someone explain the behaviour?

Comment: Read the answer to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24421658/how-does-circular-import-work-exactly-in-python

Comment: @rje The problem is that he's importing the modules `a` and `b` from the current directory, not functions. If it were two files importing functions from each other, then that answer would be relevant.

Answer (score 0):

All packages depend on eachother in order. Note that they also must be in the same directory